# How can I find out which columns in a Postgres database could be NOT nullable?

Tags: database, postgresql, null, data-cleaning

We have some legacy code+data which was a bit lazy when it comes to setting `NOT NULL` restrictions on columns (ditto for the code which generates the data).

It's not always known whether these columns should be nullable or not (sometimes features were written years ago).

It would be great to look in our real data to see if any of these columns are NULLABLE but happen to have no NULL values in. We might consider some of these as candidates to add not null restrictions on.

(Obviously, merely having no nulls doesn't mean it this doesn't necessarily mean they should be not-nullable: we might just have got unlucky, but it's a good place to start)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION any_is_null(col TEXT, tab TEXT, OUT tmp BOOL) RETURNS boolean  
AS $$  
  BEGIN  
    EXECUTE format('SELECT 
                   true 
                   from %s 
                   WHERE %s IS NULL LIMIT 1
                   ', tab, col) into tmp;
  END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

select c.table_schema,
       c.table_name,
       c.column_name,
       case c.is_nullable
            when 'NO' then 'false'
            when 'YES' then 'true'
       end as nullable,
       CASE 
         WHEN any_is_null(c.column_name, c.table_name) IS NULL 
            AND c.is_nullable = 'YES' 
         THEN true 
         ELSE FALSE 
       END as could_be_non_nullable

from information_schema.columns c
join information_schema.tables t
     on c.table_schema = t.table_schema 
     and c.table_name = t.table_name
where c.table_schema in ('public')
      and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
order by table_schema,
         table_name,
         column_name;
```

Replace the `where c.table_schema in ('public')` with the schema(s) you want to focus on.

Don't forget to drop the function after you're done.

PS: This will probably max out your database if you have a lot of columns with no NULL values in as each column will get full table-scanned) so be careful!